# docker-compose start/up without running command

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is there any way to make docker-compose start a service without running the declared command?

Not sure if any such option exists, nothing obvious in the flags for [docker-compose up](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/). It would be useful for debugging as presently I have to comment out the command in order to enter a container that otherwise exits on startup.

In this case, there's no `command` in the Dockerfile, but there's a `command` in docker-compose.yml.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53045181/9381897).

Comment: It depends how you have it set up. If a separate ENTRYPOINT and CMD are correctly set up, you can use [`docker-compose run`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/) to run some command other than the default in one of the containers, which will start any others in the network that the specified service requires. From the question, though, it's hard to be more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on jonrsharpe's comment, the answer is to use `run` instead as it will start the container.

> docker-compose run service bash

This makes it possible to enter the container and debug the problem so the real command can run.

Comment: For me this started a new instance of the container rather than start bash in the existing container that I normally bring up with `./docker-compose -f up service`