# Where are the directory created from dockerfile and how do I access it?

Tags: docker

I am new to Docker and have a simple question. Let say I created an image to `mkdir` a folder using dockerfile below:

```
FROM biocontainers/biocontainers:latest

USER root

RUN mkdir -p /bin/testFolder
```

I built the image as below:

```
docker image build -f dockerfile -t tmp:test .
```

The message output is as below:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  12.77GB
Step 1/3 : FROM biocontainers/biocontainers:latest
latest: Pulling from biocontainers/biocontainers
22dc81ace0ea: Pull complete
1a8b3c87dba3: Pull complete
91390a1c435a: Pull complete
07844b14977e: Pull complete
b78396653dae: Pull complete
37acb86aada8: Pull complete
dea6dd7e30dd: Pull complete
5f8154b871f1: Pull complete
06b022b2c83f: Pull complete
9b2c8a4ecb8d: Pull complete
7b30ef549338: Pull complete
9b34fc643fc1: Pull complete
52c0fab077ab: Pull complete
db8c4567241d: Pull complete
db7cd43b1320: Pull complete
c0db2ee4b7f4: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:c6f082f5658c6d31a5ccb537289d1ce777f51b7285c465fe0efa219058471c81
Status: Downloaded newer image for biocontainers/biocontainers:latest
 ---> 932119eee190
Step 2/3 : USER root
 ---> Running in a707d5e1b39d
Removing intermediate container a707d5e1b39d
 ---> a1c02b8e9ed3
Step 3/3 : RUN mkdir -p /bin/testFolder
 ---> Running in 88f453470cc6
Removing intermediate container 88f453470cc6
 ---> 12d57c57c415
Successfully built 12d57c57c415
Successfully tagged tmp:test
```

How do I know where `/bin/testFolder` is located and how do I access it? Thanks.

Comment: Its located in `/bin/testFolder`?

Comment: Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53045181/9381897).

Answer (score 2):

As of now, you have built the image. Next step is to run the container with `docker run -d --name  container-name image-name` for e.g. `docker run -d --name myfirstcontainer tmp:test`

The directory is located inside the container. You can enter the container with `docker exec -it myfirstcontainer bash`

Comment: I received `Error response from daemon: Container 450b1cdb06c10a5c20b5d4dfea1fe9e91baf2c4345565bd2949cfe00e6cb89ad is not running`: when I ran `docker exec -it myfirstcontainer bash`

Comment: This means that your container either crashed, or finished execution. You could start your image directly in `bash` by issuing this command: `docker run -it <image> /bin/bash`

Comment: @bison72 you can enter the container only when it is running. run docker ps to list the running containers

Comment: @bison72 currently your dockerfile is not running any process that’s why. Try this example https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/