# Inspect docker container at container startup

Tags: docker, containers, inspect

I downloaded an image which immediately stops. How can I inspect it (or any container spawned from it)?

I cannot use anything like `docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID bash` since I don't have time to get the `CONTAINER_ID`.

(`docker run -it 5413e661e579 bash` does not help, it starts the container and stops immediatly.)

I don't know how the image was built, I don't have the Dockerfile ; the only thing I know is the entrypoint: `["python" "app.py"]` but it does not output anything useful.

**Answer [from duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53045181/719276):**

`docker run -it --entrypoint "/bin/bash" image_name`

Comment: Do you want to inspect a specific container or you just want to explore image's content? For the later, you may find this [helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53045112/explore-dockers-image-files-if-container-exits-immediately/53045181#53045181).

Comment: Thanks your answer on the other question is perfect, can you post it here as well? I know my question is an almost duplicate, so you could flag it as duplicate instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Explore Docker's image files if container exits immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53045112/explore-dockers-image-files-if-container-exits-immediately)

Answer (score 2):

You can get the container id by passing in the `--all` flag to docker container ls

`docker container ls --all`

This will list all containers, including those that have been stopped or exited. Then, once you have the container id, inspect the logs with the [docker logs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/) command

`docker logs <container>`